# Conceptual question regarding absolute value

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

When taking cases for let's say $|x|$ we say :

It is $x$ for all $x \geq 0$
And

It is $-x$ for all $x<0$

I don't understand why we have "or equal to" in the first case

Why can't we have $\leq$ for the second case ?

Does this imply zero is positive?

This is something which I have blindly learnt without understanding why, hopefully I can change that.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in having $\le 0$ as $0=-0$

Comment: "*Does this imply $0$ is positive?*"  No.  $0$ is not positive.  $0$ is also not negative.  $0$ is however "non-negative" and is also "non-positive."  The way you saw it written is just breaking into two cases, the *non-negative* numbers and the negative numbers.

Comment: If you prefer as well, you could have written it as $|x|=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x\text{ is positive}\\0&\text{if }x\text{ is zero}\\-x&\text{if }x\text{ is negative}\end{cases}$... having split into three cases.  This requires more writing however and so is seen as less elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $0 = -0$, the following ways of writing $|x|$ are all equivalent:
\begin{align}
|x| &= \begin{cases}
-x, &x<0\\
x, & x\ge 0
\end{cases} \tag{1}\\
|x| &= \begin{cases}
-x, &x\le 0\\
x, &x \ge 0
\end{cases}\tag{2}\\
|x| &= \begin{cases}
-x, &x \le 0\\
x, &x > 0
\end{cases}\tag{3}
\end{align}

Some authors/instructors may prefer their domains of definition to be disjoint, and so prefer either $(1)$ or $(3)$, but that's just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a function piecewise, so to say $$f(x)=\begin{cases} g_1(x)&\text{if }\mathcal A(x)\\ g_2(x)&\text{if }\mathcal B(x)\\ g_3(x)&\text{if }\mathcal C(x)\end{cases},$$

it is good practice to divide the cases in such a way that conditions $\mathcal A(x)$, $\mathcal B(x)$ and $\mathcal C(x)$ are mutually exclusive. In principle, there is nothing wrong with having them not be mutuallly exclusive, but then one would need to check that, for instance, $g_1(x)=g_2(x)$ for all $x$ such that $\mathcal A(x)\land \mathcal B(x)$. Otherwise we are not defining a *function*. This necessity makes the exposition unnecessarily messy, other than being a cause of errors for people whose strong suit is the neglect of details.

In the instance of $\lvert x\rvert$, there is no reason to put the case $x=0$ with $x>0$ rather than with the other: for all that matters, you could even put it by itself and say that $$\lvert x\rvert=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x>0\\ \arcsin x&\text{if }x=0\\ -x&\text{if }x<0\end{cases},$$ though it's better to have fewer and simpler cases.